# AWS S3. Append data in JSON. JSON file visual format

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, append

I try to add data to existing in S3 bucket JSON file.
Initial structure:

```
{ 
           "id": "1", 
           "name": "test1",
           "limit": [20.0, 30.0]
           }
```

I add

```
{
       "id": "2", 
       "name": "test2", 
       "limit": [10.0, 20.0]
}
```

and rewrite it on bucket.
When I download it from bucket it get the next structure ""\"{\\\"id\\\": \\\"1\\\", \\r\\n\\\"name\\\"

How can I reformat it in JSON format?

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
bucket = 'bucket'

local_data = {"id": "123", "name": "XYZ", "transaction": [20.0, 30.0]}

local_data_json = json.dumps(local_data)
resp=s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key='key.json')
data=resp.get('Body').read()

json_data = json.dumps(data.decode('utf-8'))
p = json_data + local_data_json

s3.put_object(Bucket=bucket, Key='key.json', 
 Body=json.dumps(p).encode())
```

Comment: How are you reading and adding and writing data specifically?

Comment: Include that code into the question. There is no `json.loads` anywhere, you are just dumping json over and over again completely messing up the initial structure.

Comment: Add code to the ts

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is doing everything with strings, rather than converting strings into objects.

The `json.dumps(obj)` command converts a Python object into a **JSON string**.

To convert a JSON string into a **Python object**, use `json.loads(str)`.

Therefore, your code should be doing something like this (I didn't test it):

```py
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
bucket = 'bucket'

local_data = {"id": "123", "name": "XYZ", "transaction": [20.0, 30.0]}

resp=s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key='key.json')
data=resp.get('Body').read()

json_data = json.loads(data.decode('utf-8'))  # Changed
p = json_data + local_data                    # Changed

s3.put_object(Bucket=bucket, Key='key.json', 
 Body=json.dumps(p).encode())
```